# No Tailwind tips in WebStorm

Tags: webstorm, tailwind-css

I know tips could shown, but right now I can't see it. What do I need to do?
I have installed tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer libraries.

[That's what I told about autocomplete popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZmkZi.png)

Comment: could you clarify what tips are meant? what Webstorm version do you use?

Comment: Tips are ones that hint you what options can be written next. So, I have no such tips with some reason.

Comment: @FerelUltra Do you mean that you see no entries in the Code Completion popup? Better clarification (e.g. a screenshot) would help quite a bit in understanding your issue.

Comment: Yes, you are right. There is no entries(suggestion) popup that provide autocomplete.

Comment: I updated issue by sending a picture of what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was 2021.2 version that for some reason can't autocomplete tailwind CSS classes. 2021.3 fix the problem. Better use JetBrains developer tools.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).